# Dynamically select Radio button on page load in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have 2 radio buttons and either one can be the default radio button depending on certain criteria. I have been trying to get them to default with no success.

JSP page:

```jsp
<fieldset>

    <legend>Select Target File</legend>

    <s:radio id="targetFileRadioSelect" name="targetFileRadio" title="Select Baseline Configuration File" list="#{'S' : 'Select Baseline Configuration File'}" value ="targetFileValue"/>

    <s:select list="targetFilesList" name="selectedTargetFile" />

    <s:radio id="targetFileRadioCreate" name="targetFileRadio" title="Create Base Baseline Configuration File" list="#{'C' : 'Create Base Baseline Configuration File'}" value ="targetFileValue"/>

    <label>File Name:</label>
    <input id="targetFileName"  name="targetFileName" size="20" maxlength="50" style="visibility : visible" type="text" value="<s:property value='targetFileName'/>" />

    <label>File Description:</label>
    <input id="targetFileDescription"  name="targetFileDescription" size="20" maxlength="50" style="visibility : visible" type="text" value="<s:property value='targetFileDescription'/>" />

</fieldset>
```

I created the property in my action class and this is how its being set:

```
private String targetFileValue;

public String getTargetFileValue() {
    return targetFileValue;
}

public void setTargetFileValue(String targetFileValue) {
    this.targetFileValue = targetFileValue;
}

if(extensionMatch == null)
{
    // No extension matched default to the Create New Radio Button  
    setTargetFileValue("C");
}
else
{
    // An extension match was found default to Select Baseline Radio Button and make the matching extension be first in the list
    setTargetFileValue("S");
}
```

Is there anything that i might be over looking?

Comment: See the output HTML generated from Struts tags or use `s:debug`.

Comment: @Roman C
i used s:debug and the targetFileValue is S, which it should default if i am understanding this correctly but for some reason it is not

Comment: @Roman It turned out that my problem was my page not reflecting my changes. I would change the jsp and compile but the changes were not being pushed out for some reason. After messing with it more i was able to get the changes pushed out and it defaults perfectly :)  Thanks Roman for your time